# Action of a Linear Functional on a Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I was hoping to find a good canonical reference for the mathematics behind something called the action of a linear functional $L$ on a polynomial $p(x)$ which is denoted $\langle L|p(x)\rangle$

Assuming we have $\Pi$ is the algebra of polynomials of a single variable over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\Pi^*$ the vector space of all linear functionals on $\Pi$.  The definition I an seeing is

$$\langle cL+c'L'|p(x)\rangle=c\langle L|p(x)\rangle+c'\langle L'|p(x)\rangle$$

But without having been formally introduced to it in a course, I was wondering if there was a particular reference that would be a good authoratative starting point to working with these actions.  Does anyone know of any good literature on these actions of a linear functional?

Comment: This is simple linear algebra: a linear functional is just a linear map from a general vector space to the definition field taken as a linear space of dimension one over itself. The set of all these linear functionas on a certain space $\;V\;$ is denoted $\;V^*\;$ and it is a linear space itself with the usual definitions of addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: that's not the definition, which is $\langle L|p+q\rangle = \langle L|p\rangle +\langle L|q\rangle,$ with $\langle L|cp\rangle = c \langle L|p\rangle$ Examples include $\langle L|p\rangle = p(7),$ or $\langle L|p\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x) e^{-x^2} dx$ The second example can be split into two ordinary real integrals if we write $p(x) = r(x) + i s(x),$ with all coefficients of $r,s$ real.

Comment: The paper I was reading had it defined as I did above.

Comment: What paper are you reading, then?

Comment: When I get home I can give you the paper and author.

Comment: @WillJagy, the paper is "Umbral Calculus and Sheffer Sequences of Polynomials",  Authors Taekyun Kim, Dae San Kim, etc. Journal of Mathematical Physics.

Comment: [here](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/54/8/10.1063/1.4817853) is a link